# Keystone log files always empty

Tags: openstack

I am walking through the Ubuntu walk-through for installing OpenStack.  I am past the keystone stage and I find that it creates log files in /var/log/keystone which are always zero length.  I also get the following message in the response to many commands that otherwise work:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "keystoneclient.v2_0.client"
```

-- this may or may not be related.   Any advice for a noob appreciated.

This is the Folsom release.

Comment: that warning is specific to python-keystoneclient .  that is the keystone command line utility and not part of keystone itself.  so, that warning ( probably not an issue ) is not directly related to keystone.  HOWEVER if your logging device is non existent or not named in a normal fashion.  That could confuse many applications.

Comment: @MattJoyce thanks for your input.  I am still not sure why when the service keystone starts, it manages to create the log file /var/log/keystone/keystone.log -- but never any entries.   I think one of the logging handlers is either not present or not configured.

Answer (score 1):

Keystone uses /etc/keystone/logging.conf to control logging levels. By default, the keystone logger will only show WARNING level messages and above:

```
[logger_root]
level=WARNING
handlers=file
```

If you change level to something lower (e.g., `INFO`, `DEBUG`) then restart the keystone service, you should see log messages appear in /var/log/keystone/keystone.log